# Ionic Resources does not update platforms/android/res files

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

When I run `ionic resources` or `ionic resources android`, it says the splash screen and icons are generating for both iOS and Android. However, when I check the res folder under platforms for android, the icons are unchanged after running `ionic build android` or `ionic run android --device`. I have tried cleaning the cache, uninstalling the app and reinstalling, and even manually trying to set the icons in the platform folder but none of that has worked. The iOS icons/splash screen work fine.

Comment: How does your config.xml look like?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/BRzETLUw

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem this week. Here is what I did.

Based on [this blog post](http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/) I got it working for me with the following steps:

1) Create a new hook in

> hooks/after_prepare/020_android_move_custom_resources.js

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

// This hook copies various resource files
// from our version control system directories
// into the appropriate platform specific location

var customResources = [{
    "pathToResources/android/other/notification_icon.png":
        "platforms/android/res/drawable/notification_icon.png"
    }, {
    "pathToResources/android/other/thatOtherImg.png":
        "platforms/android/res/thatOtherFolder/thatOtherImg.png"
    }
];

var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

// no need to configure below
var rootDir = process.argv[2];

customResources.forEach(function(obj) {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
        var val = obj[key];
        var srcFile = path.join(rootDir, key);
        var destFile = path.join(rootDir, val);
        var destDir = path.dirname(destFile);
        if (fs.existsSync(srcFile) && fs.existsSync(destDir)) {
            fs.createReadStream(srcFile).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(destFile));
        }
    });
});
```

2) Put all the resources you want to copy over into the `customResources` array, each in his own object. The key is the source, the value the destination.

3) Make the hook exectuable

```
$ chmod +x hooks/after_prepare/020_android_move_custom_resources.js
```

This got it working. This way, anyone who clones my git project will also get the files copied upon compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this problem. This seems to be an issue with Cordova 6 and is supposed to have been fixed in 6.1. Here is the related url - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/1638

The files seem to be copied into the res folder under root folder correctly when you run the ionic resources command but somewhere down the line during the build process, the files dont get copied to the final destination which is the res folder under platforms/android folder.

I followed a quick manual step of just copying the contents of res folder from under root folder into platforms/android/res folder. Take care not to erase other folders from the destination folder such as values and xmls.

After this the icon and splash screens work just fine.

Unfortunately, I dont have a better solution at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to get this to work as fast as possible.

```
ionic cordova resources android;
cd resources/android/splash;
mkdir ../assets;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-land-hdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-land-ldpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-land-mdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-land-xhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-land-xxhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-land-xxxhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-port-hdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-port-ldpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-port-mdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-port-xhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-port-xxhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/drawable-port-xxxhdpi;
cp drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-land-hdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-land-ldpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-land-mdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-land-xhdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-land-xxhdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-land-xxxhdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-port-hdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-port-ldpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-port-mdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-port-xhdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-port-xxhdpi/screen.png;
cp drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png ../assets/drawable-port-xxxhdpi/screen.png;
cd ../icon;
mkdir ../assets/mipmap-hdpi;
mkdir ../assets/mipmap-ldpi;
mkdir ../assets/mipmap-mdpi;
mkdir ../assets/mipmap-xhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/mipmap-xxhdpi;
mkdir ../assets/mipmap-xxxhdpi;
cp drawable-hdpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-hdpi/icon.png;
cp drawable-ldpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-ldpi/icon.png;
cp drawable-mdpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-mdpi/icon.png;
cp drawable-hdpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-hdpi/icon.png;
cp drawable-xhdpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-xhdpi/icon.png;
cp drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-xxhdpi/icon.png;
cp drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png ../assets/mipmap-xxxhdpi/icon.png;
cd ../assets;
cp -rf ./* ../../../platforms/android/res/;
cd ../../..;
```

The first line executes the normal resources generation. Then the rest is for formatting the files and moving them to the correct destination.
You could create a .sh script and past this code into it for the ease of use.